# IBAction for Buttons inside static Cell do not work with didSelectRowAtIndexPath is overrided

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton, ibaction

I have some static `UITableViewCell`s. One of them with 5 buttons inside. Inside  `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` I handle the selection event for all the cells except for the one with the buttons inside. The problem is the action for the buttons in that one cell does not work.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: please provide your code here

Comment: when you select row did select method gets called but not the buttons target method so it is good if you set some tag to button and then call the button using it's tag value.

Comment: thanks for your reply
the problem is when touching inside the cell didSelectRowAtIndexPath is called but when touching inside  one of the buttons themsleves neither the IBAction nor didSelectRowAtIndexPath is called

Comment: you have to create button programmatically in cellForRowAtIndexPath and write target method for button

Comment: Check if buttons have a selector to call.

Comment: you need to add target for particular buttons

Comment: but  my tableView have static cells

Comment: i have IBAction selector for the buttons in a custom UITableViewCell class
where i need to handle the touch events for these buttons

Comment: instead of create IBAction in UITableViewCell class, make property of each button and add target for each button in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: I have static cells so i do not have cellForAtIndexPath @TejasArdeshna

Answer (score 1):

Finally I figured out That the root of the problem was at a completely different area, `heightForRowAtIndexPath` was returning wrong height for that cell (actually smaller height),

So, the controller interpreted the touches to be in a completely different place than the actual place I was supposedly touching

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the `cellForAtIndexPath` method, however you can implement the `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` method and add target for each button like so:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // get a reference to button
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```